# Take field with a string of values and extract it to 1-1 value / column

Tags: views

I have a Drupal 8 view with a field, *favorite pets*, which allows multiple values rendered as a CSV string (e.g. *cat, dog, snake*).  What I would like is having the following output.

```
+ id  + cat  + dog + snake +
============================
|  1  |  1   | 1   | 1     |
|  2  |      | 1   |       |
|  3  |      |     |       |
```

I was looking for a way to solve this, but I hit a wall trying to determine if this is a theming or possibly a back-end (e.g. `hook_views_data()`) issue.

Comment: What information do you need to take this off hold?  I have a view with a field that renders a string as a csv and I want it so each value has its own column.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I must be too close too the problem because I thought my original version was more helpful than the edited version.  Please give me an idea of what needs to be added to make this question better.

Comment: The problem is not knowing how the output is and how you want it. The problem is that what you are asking is _I hit a wall trying to determine if this is a theming or possibly a back-end (e.g. `hook_views_data()`) issue_. Between what you describe as you want to obtain and what you are asking there is a gap: You are talking of an issue, but you don't describe what that issue is. It could be you are using the _issue_ term differently from what I am expecting, but _issue_ is a synonym of _problem_.

Comment: Actually, the sentence I quoted is not even a question, but a sentence stating a fact: You don't know if it is a problem with theming (the field, I guess) or with the back-end. The distinction between _theming_ and _back-end_ is the other problem. What distinction do you see between _theming_ and _back-end_?